# Updating field by Document Id

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Actually, I have Document Ids of my collection but how can I update a field of in Collection through Document Id.

Like I want to change the status from booked to unbooked on a button click.
like I've id but I want to change field from unbooked to booked on a click event

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92Djj.png)

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Time_Slot_Modal Time_Slot_Modal = TimingArrayList.get(position);
        holder.tvtime.setText(Time_Slot_Modal.getTime());

        holder.btbook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               String idholder = Time_Slot_Modal.getId();



           Log.e("12344", "==="+q);
                Log.e("12344", "===" + idholder);

            }
        });

    }
    public Boolean booktoday() {
            boolean booktoday = false;
            q = db.collection("Time Slots").whereEqualTo("status","unbooked");
            q.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    Log.e("2456", "+++++====");
//                TimingArrayList.clear();
                    if (!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {
                        Log.e("2456", "+++++----");
                        List<DocumentSnapshot> list1 = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments();
                        for (DocumentSnapshot d : list1) {
                            Time_Slot_Modal c = d.toObject(Time_Slot_Modal.class);
                            c.setId(d.getId());

                        TimingArrayList.remove(c);
//
                        myAdapterTime.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }

                    }
                }
            });

            return booktoday;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post your database structure so we could help. Also, you can check out this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data?

Comment: Please edit your question and show us what you have tried and what exactly doesn't work the way you expect. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

You should update a document by calling

```
db.collection("Time Slots").doc(id).update(...) or .set()
```

Just remember the call is an asynchronous function, you need handle them properly.